# Iterating through a string with different possible characters

Tags: python, python-3.4

I just signed up here because I am taking an online course in Python and have been using this site to help me through the course. I am; however, stuck.

I am not posting my actual homework assignment, but rather just an element of my code I am having a difficult time with...

I am trying to iterate through a string using a list containing letters in the alphabet. I want to have each letter in the list iterate through the word at different indexes. For example:

word = "panda"
char_list = ['a','b','c'] etc... 
Output should be aanda, panda, paada ......
Followed by banda,pbnda,pabda,...

My code iterates through the word using only the first character in the list. 
Sorry, I am super NEW to coding in general...

```
index = 0
word = "panda"
possible_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'o']
for char in possible_char:
    while index < len(word):
        new_word = word[:index] + char + word[index + 1:]
        print (new_word)
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: You forgot to update the `index` counter. Set it to *0* after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop only works for the first iteration of the outer `for` loop because `index` does not get reset and remains at `len(word)` after it finshes the first time. Try moving the line where you initialize it to `0` inside the outer loop:

```
for char in possible_chars:
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        #...
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.
You just need to reset the index to zero. So after the for loop your first command should be `index=0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
index = 0
word = "panda"
possible_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'o']
for char in possible_char:
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        new_word = word[:index] + char + word[index + 1:]
        print (new_word)
        index = index + 1
```

you have to re-initialize index on the forloop, just to start all over again on the word

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset the index back to 0 after you are done iterating with each char .

```
index = 0
word = "panda"
possible_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'o']
for char in possible_char:
   index=0
   while index < len(word):
      new_word = word[:index] + char + word[index + 1:]
      print (new_word)
      index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialise the index counter in the for loop:

```
index = 0
word = "panda"
possible_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'o']
for char in possible_char:
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        new_word = word[:index] + char + word[index + 1:]
        print (new_word)
        index = index + 1
```